# How to fix INSERT INTO SELECT group function error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm learning oracle SQL right now and I'm stuck on a problem where I have to use an INSERT INTO SELECT statement to populate a table based on a query. I need the table to be populated with information relating to employees that make less than the company average salary AND work on at least two projects. Below are the tables I'm working with and my code, please tell me where I'm going wrong as I'm getting a group by function error with my current code. Thanks!

Tables:

- `Division` (DID, dname, managerID)
- `Employee` (empID, name, salary, DID)
- `Workon` (PID, EmpID, hours)
- `Promotion_list` (empID, name, salary, divisionName)

Code:

```
insert into Promotion_list
    select e.empid, e.name, e.salary, d.dname
    from employee e 
    inner join division d on e.did = d.did 
    inner join workon w on w.empid = e.empid
    where e.salary < (select avg(salary) from employee) 
      and count(w.pid) >= 2
```

Comment: count(*) is an aggregate function.  You need a group by somewhere  Have you read up on GROUP BY?

Answer (score 3):

Count function can't be in `where`, but can be in `having` clause which means that you'll also need `group by` all non-aggregated columns.

Something like this:

```
insert into Promotion_list (empID, name, salary, divisionName)
  select e.empid, e.name, e.salary, d.dname
  from employee e inner join division d on e.did = d.did 
                  inner join workon w   on w.empid = e.empid
  where e.salary < (select avg(salary) from employee) 
  group by e.empid, e.name, e.salary, d.dname
  having count(w.pid) >= 2
```

I don't know whether it'll return result you expect, but - at least - shouldn't raise an error.